# django-filter: How to concatenate columns

Tags: python, django, django-filter

How to concatenate `User.first_name` and `last_name` in the same field when using `django-filter`?

I'd like to have a single form field for querying something like `John Smith`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CharFilter` in your `FilterSet` and pass in a custom QuerySet to the `method` kwarg.

Example:

```
def name_concat_filter(queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=value) | Q(last_name__icontains=value))
name = CharFilter(method=name_concat_filter)
```

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#method